# access wordpress site from another machine

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, wamp

I'am new to the WordPress and I created WordPress website and configure it within the Wamp Server. The site displays all it's contains locally correctly. Now I want to access that website from the another machine within same network but it did not display all the contents correctly. it displays only the text. no images and the applied theme is not displays. I turn off the firewall and change the Apache configuration file (httpd.config) as follows. but it also didn't work properly.  please help me.

Order allow, deny

Allow from all

Comment: what url are you using to access the site from the other machine?

Comment: The ip address of host machine is 192.168.0.4. So I used http://192.168.0.4/wordpress from another machine to access the host machine.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you specify during install that the hostname of the site is "**localhost**". Unofrtunately when you connect from another computer the link to "**localhost**" refers to the pc you are connecting from and since in this pc there isn't any server runnin,g you see only the text and not the images or the css.
The solution is to modify the `wp-config.php` wordpress file and change this from:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

to:

```
define('DB_HOST', '192.168.0.4');
```

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: @Lee cause I am a fre*king sysadmin

Why the downvote? I use wordpress every day and this is a common error, I've fix it with this solution several time, because this is the solution!

Comment: I get what you're saying, and I actually agree.. but the point I'm trying to make, is that you've made an assumption without actually asking what the value of the host is for this user. I think on SO rules and guidelines, that's not technically substantial proof to make an answer. But I'll reverse the downvote, because I do agree this probably seems to be the cause. FYI, I also use Wordpress everyday.

Comment: IN the comments the OP says that the host is 192.168.0.4. The problem of user which is that you can see only the text and not the css or other graphical files is triggered if you use "localhost" as hostname. So yes I made an assumption based on my know-how and I'm deeply sure that the answer fits the SO rules and the TS request. We have to wait the answer from the OP :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with URL of the site. You need to update the URL in database and replace localhost with IP of your machine using phpmyadmin and then that site will be accessible from other machines in your network. Please try this and it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a WordPress oddity. When you install WP on localhost, or anywhere, it stores the url used in the install in its database. It then uses this url internally in its code to build links etc.

So when you come to run this site from another PC, things like image links will be built with the url `localhost` or `localhost/wordpress`.

Now when you run this from another PC using a different URL like `192.168.0.4/wordpress` `localhost` will still appear in the links and of course there is no `localhost` on the client PC. So the links dont work. Its a bit like you have moved your site to a new url, but WP does not know about it.

Read this post [on the WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) to work out what you need to so to amend the urls in the database. OF course this means you wont be able to use `localhost` anymore on the WAMPServer machine either.